# Заменить цикл с помощью numpy—ускорить вычисление кумулятивной суммы

Tags: python, производительность, numpy, ctypes

Имеется массив `[-1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1]`.

С помощью такого цикла каждый следующий элемент становится суммой предыдущих:

```
for i in range(BESTRESULT.shape[0] - 1):
    BESTRESULT[i + 1] = BESTRESULT[i + 1] + BESTRESULT[i]
```

Общее время выполнения кода из-за этого цикла увеличивается ровно в два раза.
Есть острейшая необходимость заменить данный код на что-либо более быстрое. Желательно с использованием *NumPy*.

Comment: какой результат должен получится из этого массива, просто чтобы логику понять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть `numpy` массив `a`:

```
a = numpy.array([-1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1])
```

То чтобы найти кумулятивную сумму, достаточно [`numpy.cumsum()` вызвать](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html):

```
>>> a.cumsum()
array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  2,  1,  2,  1])
```

Простое сравнение показывает разницу ~70 раз по сравнению с кодом в вопросе на моей машине (`ipython`):

```
In [0]: import numpy    
In [1]: a = numpy.repeat(1, 1000000)
In [2]: %timeit a.copy()
1000 loops, best of 3: 937 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit a.cumsum()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.39 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit a.copy().cumsum()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.31 ms per loop

In [5]: def cumsum_mihail(a): # код из вопроса
    for i in range(a.shape[0] - 1):
        a[i + 1] = a[i + 1] + a[i]

In [6]: %timeit cumsum_mihail(a.copy())
1 loop, best of 3: 477 ms per loop
```

Comment: я как раз делал сравниение (timeit) для этих двух решений... Но раз вы уже ответили, то может добавите сравниение в ваш ответ для массива из ~1M элементов? У меня разница в скорости (по сравнению с решением от @Александр) - 42.5 раз получилась...

Comment: @MaxU ясно, что cumsum() быстрее чем явный цикл для numpy массивов (так как очень медленно по одному элементу из numpy массива обрабатывать). Но чтобы цифры показывать, необходимо больше информации, иначе много вариантов перебирать: 1- по месту вычислять (`out=a`) или копия 2- тип float, int 3- откуда исходные данные и какой размер. (Случай с 10 элементами, может отличаться от 1000, 1000_000, 1000_000_000 4. Какое железо? Какой CPU? какая версия numpy? Какие-то вещи могут не иметь значения. Не измеряя сложно сказать. Легко дать вариант, который быстрее вероятно кода в вопросе, но

Comment: .. качественное сравнение гораздо тяжелее. Легко бессмысленные вводящие в заблуждение цифры получить. Если не знаете точную цель, то лучше не приводить цифр (если ограниченность результатов явно не указана или не ясна из контекста). Вы можете попробовать сравнение провести, если есть желание.

Comment: я считаю, что сравнение производительности на одном о том же железе для одних и тех же данных (возможно для нескольких массивов разной длины) помешать не может...

Comment: @MaxU если представить результаты как: "вот код, который я на своей машине запустил для таких-то данных и получил такие-то результаты" и не обещать, что данные бОльшую применимость имеют, то можно чисто для иллюстрации (чтобы было ясно, что по крайней мере в одном случае один код, быстрее другого). Проблема в том, что люди более широкие выводы, недостаточно обоснованные данными, будут делать.

Answer (score 1):

Вот сравнение скорости (на моем железе) для NumPy массива, состоящего из 1-го миллиона случайым образом выбранных элементов. Все элементы массива принадлежат след. множеству:  `[-1, 0, 1]`:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import accumulate

a = np.random.choice([-1,0,1], 10**6)
```

Замеры для массива из 1-го миллиона элементов:

```
In [5]: x = a.copy()

In [6]: %%timeit
   ...: for i in range(x.shape[0] - 1):
   ...:     x[i + 1] = x[i + 1] + x[i]
   ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 436 ms per loop

In [7]: x = a.copy()

In [8]: %timeit x.cumsum()
   ...:
100 loops, best of 3: 2.79 ms per loop

In [9]: x = a.copy()

In [10]: %timeit list(accumulate(x))
    ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 120 ms per loop
```

Замеры для массива из 1-й тысячи элементов:

```
In [11]: a = np.random.choice([-1,0,1], 10**3)

In [12]: x = a.copy()

In [13]: %%timeit
    ...: for i in range(x.shape[0] - 1):
    ...:     x[i + 1] = x[i + 1] + x[i]
    ...:
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop

In [14]: x = a.copy()

In [15]: %timeit x.cumsum()
    ...:
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.62 µs per loop

In [16]: x = a.copy()
    ...:

In [17]: %timeit list(accumulate(x))
    ...:
10000 loops, best of 3: 99.4 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, и вам нужна накопленная сумма последовательности, то лучше использовать itertools.accumulate. По идее, оно должно работать очень быстро.

```
from itertools import accumulate

BESTRESULT = [-1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1]

BESTRESULT = accumulate(BESTRESULT)

print(list(BESTRESULT))

# [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1]
```

UPD: Сейчас провёл сравнение.
Мой вариант с accumulate отрабатывает список из миллиона элементов на моей машине примерно за 0,04 секунды. Ваш вариант с циклом делает то же самое за 0,29 секунд.
То есть, предложенный мной вариант даёт выигрыш в скорости более, чем в семь раз.